# Pushbutton Debounce

Tags: button, synchronization, push, vhdl, keypad

As the title suggests, and since I don't know a more formal name for it, my problem is that when I push a button in a 4X4 membrane keypad and while it's being pushed, it adds too many inputs to the system. It seems a silly question but I don't want any hardware components to get rid of this problem. I mean if I have chance to solve it by using only VHDL coding, I will be very glad. To clarify myself, I don't want any sort of code that accomplishes the job. What I am asking is that I just want a method name to start with. (like debouncing pushbuttons) And by the way, I don't want to mess with the clock since I've already divided the clock to determine which button is being pressed in the keypad. But if it is the only solution, then I'm okay with it.

What I want is simply when the user keeps pushing the button such as 4 in the keypad, it should be seen as one input, but if the user push it again not continually but one at a time, then it should be adding another 4 to the system. Finally, I know the question is very subtle since I didn't provide any code. And as you easily notice, I am new to all this stuff. So, sorry for the inconvenience. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget to mention which fpga I am using. It is spartan 3E-100 Cp132.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The thing you are experiencing is due to so called bouncing of the key, which is basically very rapid change in the signal level when a key is pressed and released. Since these changes are all recorded, inputs get added in your case.

You will need to include a key debounce method such as the one explained in this [link](http://www.deathbylogic.com/2011/03/vhdl-debounce/). One could debounce by increasing the sampling interval, but more elegant way is to have a state machine which avoids re-registering of input, once it is registered. This will achieve the desired effect of the key being held pressed and still only one input being registered.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It seems the answer I was looking for. I get the basic idea for debouncing, but code seems complicated. For example, if DBx is '1', then does it mean that the pushbutton is debounced or in other words, am I safe to use it if it is '1'?

Comment: @user3100463 Well `DBx` is the debounced version of the signal `x`. So if you use the `Debounce` entity from the link, just feed the signal from the key to the input of `Debounce`, and use the output `DBx` wherever you were using `x` before. And please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it helped/sloved the problem.